# OpenAI Whisper; FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python-3.x, filenotfounderror, openai-whisper

I wanted to check out OpenAI whisper and see if I could find some personal applications for it.
I went on github and followed the instructions to set it up.
My primary system is on Windows 11 and I get this error; "**FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified**" when trying to run the test script on my system.

Things I did to troubleshoot:

- Disabled MS defender and all antivirus.
- Moved the script and audio file to the same directory.
- Moved the script and audio file to various directories.
- Ran VSCODE with admin privileges.
- Tried the "command-line usage".
- Tried everything above on a second system that run windows 10.
- The script ran on a third system with Ubuntu installed.

I think this might be a permission issue from windows but I can't seem to resolve it, any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.
I would prefer not to use the linux system because it lacks a dGPU.

Answer (score 12):

I initially ran into this same problem and it was entirely related to installing ffmpeg. You need to install it as a python module (with `pip install ffmpeg`) and from here (https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) while following these instructions: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/

Comment: Of note: This mostly worked for me, but I had to install ffmpeg-python, not ffmpeg, or else I ran into the 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'input'"" error at https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/issues/174. To fix I had to uninstall ffmpeg and ffmpeg-python both first, and then install ffmpeg-python.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by installing ffmpeg and adding the ffmpeg binary to my PATH environment variable. I was using the cmd.exe terminal not Code.

Edit: Tested in VS Code and it worked there too after including ffmpeg binary in PATH.

Comment: I installed ffmpeg via pip and added the file path to my PATH environment, no success.

Comment: Have you tested the command line tool with no success too? I.e. whisper test.wav

Comment: For me, it still didn't work after the pip install of ffmpeg. But after I installed it with homebrew (`brew install ffmpeg`) it worked. I guess for Ubuntu it would be `apt install ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 6):

It is happening due to the **ffmpeg** not working correctly or failed to load. Try running

```
ffmpeg -version
```

It should display something like this:-
[image]

If you get this, it means your ffmpeg is working fine. If you are not getting these details then try installing using below command. Hopefully it should work.

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

After installing via conda it works for me:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, the key is to install ffmpeg.exe and have it accessible via command prompt. So, the solution should be:

1. Install ffmpeg.exe (executable version, not source) to local directory (anywhere)
2. Add ffmpeg folder path to PATH environment variable
3. Open a Command Prompt and test if cmd: "ffmpeg -version" finds it or not. If not working, step #2 is still not correct and will run into "File not found" error when running whisper related code.

There are a few ways to add path to env %PATH%, but if you prefer manual GUI way, just right-click on Start Menu, open "System" and search for "environment variables".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, then I solved like this:

- Open powershell in **administration** mode
- ran `choco install ffmpeg` command

When you run in admin mode, then it automatically updates the `PATH` variable and everything worked fine afterwards

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by David Gordon, the problem lies with the absence of **ffmpeg** on your system.

You can install it on windows using one of these instructions as given in Whisper's github [README.md](https://github.com/openai/whisper) file. One way is installing it using Chocolatey (https://chocolatey.org/):

from cmd or Powershell try:
`choco install ffmpeg`